# Recursion inside loops

Tags: c, recursion

So there was an assignment given by my professor on recursion the question is as follows

Problem 1:
You are given scales for weighing loads. On the left side lies a single stone of known weight W < 2N . You own a set of N different weights, weighing 1, 2, 4, ..., 2<sup>N-1</sup> units of mass respectively. Determine how many possible ways there are of placing some weights on the sides of the scales, so as to balance them (put them in a state of equilibrium).

The solution was also given

```
#include <stdio.h>

int N;

int no_ways(int W, int index) {
    if (!W)
        return 1;
    if (index == N)
        return 0;

    int ans = 0, i;
    for (i = 0; i * (1 << index) <= W; i++)
        ans += no_ways(W - i * (1 << index), index + 1);

    return ans;
}

void main() {
    int W;
    scanf("%d%d", &N, &W);

    printf("%d\n", no_ways(W, 0));
    return 0;
}
```

In this I understood how the base conditions were tested however I could not understand the recursive call inside the for loop and how the value of index differs in each recursive call.

Any easier approach or help in understanding this program?

PS: I am new to recursion and this seemed to be way too complex for me to understand

Comment: C or Python? Don't tag with what you're not using.

Comment: Hint: The arguments are *per call*, so each call can receive different arguments.

Comment: Be careful with how deep your recursion goes when called in a loop (above it being something to keep in mind regardless). Each recursive call requires a complete function stack be set up for the recursive call. That can easily exhaust your stack space leading to StackOverflow. If `N` is large -- you may have issues.

Comment: Did you really mean 'W < 2N'? Possibly it should be 'W < 2<sup>N</sup>'...

Comment: As CiaPan points out in his answer, the code in your question is not really a solution to the problem you quoted. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin For practical purposes `N` must be less than the size of `int` in bits, which makes up to 31 levels of recursion. Not worth worrying about. The real problem of `N` being too big could be `(1<<index)` resulting with zero after pushing the `1` outside the register, hence a (theoretically) infinite recursion with `W - i * (1 << index)` equal `W`,

Answer (score 1):

In order to understand recursion, I recommend you pick some very small input values and visualize it pen & paper style:

```
// Example Input:
W = 2, N = 2

// first call
no_ways(2, 0)
// loop0: i = 0 to 2

    // first recursive call
    no_ways(2, 1)
    // loop1: i = 0 to 1

        no_ways(2, 2)
        = 0 (index == N)

        no_ways(0, 2)
        = 1 (W == 0)

    = 1 (sum of recursions in loop1)

    no_ways(1, 1)
    // loop2: i = 0 to 0

        no_ways(1, 2)
        = 0 (index == N)

    = 0 (sum of recursions in loop2)

    no_ways(0, 1)
    = 1 (W == 0)

= 2 (sum of recursions in loop0)
```

As you can see, the sequence of recursive calls and the collection of results becomes fairly complex even with this very small input, but I hope it's still readable to you.

As David C. Rankin mentioned in the comments, this algorithm is not really good. It will always reach recursion depth (number of nested calls) of `N` for any `W > 0`, even though it would be possible to detect early, when a specific recursion path is unable to produce any non-zero result.

The algorithm is written in a way, where with increasing `index` only `W` values that can be divided by `2^index` are solveable.
So (for example) any recursion of the first function call, where `W` is an odd number, will never lead to any result other than 0, since all weights with `index > 0` are even number weights.

Comment: As you can see, the result is wrong: having two weights of 1 unit and of 2 units you can balance a 2-unit stone in one way only – by putting a 2-unit weigh on the other plate. The code assumes you can put `i==2` weighs of value `1` (which is calculated with the expression `i * (1 << index)` for `index==0`), but that contradicts the description of the problem.

Comment: @CiaPan where in the problem description does it say, that you can't use 2 units of the same weight? In fact, the question author states explicitely, that the given algorithm (which allows many units of same weight) *is the solution* and he has trouble understanding it.

Comment: @CiaPan I have to admit, I first also thought about an algorithm, that assumes only one item per weight... but then the problem of telling all involved items would basically be solved by bit-position counting on the given target weight. The sentence *"You own a set of N different weights"* is not very intuitive there. It would *suggest*, that the *set* tells something about the *item count per weight*, but this is not necessarily true. Actually, the problem description just fails to tell us anything about the item count.

Comment: @CiaPan if we assumed, that there was only one item per weight, then the answer to *"Determine how many possible ways there are"* for `0 <= W <= 2N` would always be `1` - a very efficient and boring solution...

Comment: Not necessarily, if you allow weights to be put on both plates. Then you may get 5=1+4, but also 5+1=2+4 or 5+4=1+8... That's how I understand the question in the problem: _'how many possible ways there are of placing some weights on the **sides** of the scales, so as to balance them'_ – on both sides, not on just one!

Comment: As to your first comment, please note the SO question's author is not the problem's author, so the text we are given can be a mix of what the problem actually was, what the _comment_ to the problem was (given by a professor along with the example code) and what Clarence Callahan actually understood from it. However, I think the problem statement, given in the second paragraph, is an exact quotation. As such it should be taken literally – and I literally can see _'You own a set of **N different** weights'_ there, so there is _no_ possibility you have two or more weights of any given value.

Comment: @CiaPan great point... I really missed the point of putting weight on both sides of the scale. I guess the question author would need to clarify, why his given code is considered a solution to the problem statement.

Answer (score 1):

The code you present solves **different problem** than you described. So either you made a mistake in your description or the solution is wrong.

The problem your code solves has a central condition like this:

> You own a set of weights, weighing 1, 2, 4, ..., 2<sup>N-1</sup> units of mass respectively, with ***arbitrary number of each weight***

and additionally you can place those weights on **one side** of scales only (the one opposite to the stone).

This allows, for example, to balance weighing scale with a 2-unit stone in two ways, as [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60053184/733637) by grek40 shows: one solution is a single weigh of 2, the other one is two weighs 1 unit each.

Here is how your code achieves it.

The parameter `W` to a function `no_ways` represents an unbalanced (part of) weight of your stone, and the parameter `index` denotes the smallest weigh you can use. So to find all possible solutions we call `no_ways(W,0)` which corresponds to balancing the total weight of `W` with all available weighs.

The two base cases are 'there's no unbalanced weigh left', which means we found a solution, so we return 1; and 'we exhausted the allowed range of weighs`, which means we can not find a solution, so we return 0.

Then we try to expand a partial solution by trying to add the lightest available weighs to scales. The lightest weigh is `(1 << index)`, which is 2<sup>*index*</sup>, so we multiply it by increasing values of `i` and subtract it from `W`; this is done with:

```
    for (i = 0; i * (1 << index) <= W; i++)
                      (W - i * (1 << index),          )
```

and we try to balance the remaining `W - i * (1 << index)` with the next available weigh (defined by the next value of `index`) by calling:

```
    for (i = 0; i * (1 << index) <= W; i++)
               no_ways(W - i * (1 << index), index + 1)
```

Finally we accumulate the number of solutions found by summing the results:

```
    for (i = 0; i * (1 << index) <= W; i++)
        ans += no_ways(W - i * (1 << index), index + 1);
```

The sum is returned up the recursion so that at the top level we get a number of all solutions found.

I have modified you code a bit to build and print an explicit representation of each solution found. It consists of an array `int stack[]` and a variable `top`, which indicates the free position in the stack. Initially `top==0`, the stack is empty.

Whenever the `for()` loop devises a decrement to `W` it puts the value onto the stack and advances the `top` pointer, so that recursive calls build up a solution in the array. On return from the recursion we decrement `top` so that a new iteration of `for()` can put a new value at the same place.

When we have a new solution, the whole stack is printed.

Here is the code:

```
    int stack[15];
    int top = 0;

    void print_stack() {
        int k;
        for (k = 0; k < top; k ++)
            printf(" %d", stack[k]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    int N;

    int no_ways(int W, int index) {
        if (!W) {
            print_stack();
            return 1;
        }
        if (index == N)
            return 0;

        int ans = 0, i;
        for (i = 0; i * (1 << index) <= W; i++) {
            stack[top ++] = i * (1 << index);
            ans += no_ways(W - i * (1 << index), index + 1);
            top --;
        }

        return ans;
    }
```

You can easily find all lines I added — those are lines containing 'stack' or 'top'.

For the case W=2, N=2 investigated by grek40 the code prints:

```
 0 2
 2
2
```

The last line shows there are two solutions found: the first is a weight 2 obtained with one 2-unit weigh and zero 1-unit weighs (correct) and the other one is TWO one-unit weighs.

Here are the results for W=5 and N=3:

```
 1 0 4
 1 4
 3 2
 5
4
```

These are solutions: 5=1+4 (correct), 5=1+2*2 (with a weigh of 2 units used twice), 5=3*1+2 (with a weigh of 1 unit used thrice) and 5=5*1 (with five one-unit weighs).
Solutions found in total: 4.

I have tested the code in an online compiler/debugger at https://www.onlinegdb.com/

**EDIT**

For solving the problem as you stated it, that is:

> having precisely one weight equal 1 unit, one weight equal 2 units and so on through powers of 2 up to one weight of 2<sup>N-1</sup> units, which can be placed on both sides of the scales, find a balance

you could modify the solution as follows.

Every weight can be placed either on the same plate where the stone is, thus adding a weight, or on the opposite one, thus (partially) reducing the weight – or can be left alone, out of the scales. The aim is to get a zero unbalanced weight. This corresponds to satisfying an equation like

W + s<sub>0</sub>×1 + s<sub>1</sub>×2 + s<sub>2</sub>×4 + ...  + s<sub>N-1</sub>×2<sup>N-1</sup> = 0

by choosing appropriately each *s<sub>n</sub>* term equal –1, 0 or 1.
That can be achieved with a simple modification of the code:

```
int no_ways(int W, int index) {
    if (!W)
        return 1;
    if (index == N)
        return 0;

    int ans = 0, i;
    for (i = -1; i <= 1; i++)   // i equals -1, 0 or 1
        ans += no_ways(W + i * (1 << index), index + 1);

    return ans;
}
```